# IBM Integration Bus ESQL Reference to OutputRoot not working

Tags: reference, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have started working fairly recently with IBM Integration Bus v10.0.0.9, using their documentation on how it all works along with the ESQL syntax and tips.

According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bj28653_.htm#bj28653_refvar) they recommend using references to access message trees so as to not make so many navigations. They even show how to use reference variables [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bj28653_.htm#bj28653_repeats) for the OutputRoot message tree.

Knowing this, I have been trying to do the following in a ComputeNode:

```
-- ComputeNode MRM Writer
DECLARE refPointer REFERENCE TO OutputRoot.MRM.PARENT_NODE;
SET refPointer.CHILD_NODE = 'Some value';
```

In theory, this should be equivalent to:

```
SET OutputRoot.MRM.PARENT_NODE.CHILD_NODE = 'Some value';
```

However, when trying to reach the value on the next ComputeNode I find that it's null:

```
-- ComputeNode MRM Reader
DECLARE someValue CHARACTER InputRoot.MRM.PARENT_NODE.CHILD_NODE;
```

I have tried to use `CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.MRM DOMAIN 'MRM' NAME 'PARENT_NODE';` and then trying the reference but still gives a null value. And I know that the problem is from using the reference for when I use the full path the value is present. I also know that the references do work because I am using a reference variable to obtain values from the InputRoot message tree.

What can I do to make the reference work? Or is it not possible to use them for some domains and if so which ones?

### EDIT

I have noted that this problem is general and it occurs even with a regular OutputRoot.XMLNSC reference. So the problem isn't really with the MRM domain but with the references themselves.
I also noted that if I set an environment vatriable to the reference and then set the OutputRoot.MRM to the value of the environment variable it seems to work out, but it's rather redundant to do so and for some reason it sometimes fails.

```
-- Redundant workaround:
SET Environment.Variables.Output = refPointer;
SET OutputRoot.MRM.PARENT_NODE = Environment.Variables.Output;
SET Environment.Variables.Output = NULL;
```

Comment: Is the Mode of your first Compute node set to Message? You can take a [User Trace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an01310_.htm) to get some more insights what is going on.

Comment: You should not be using OutputRoot.MRM. In all currently-supported versions of IIB, the DFDL domain is a much better (and easier) alternative to the MRM domain.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann The mode is set to Message. As I have stated the problem is only present when I use references instead of directly calling the entire tree field.

Comment: @kimbert I can't change the structure that is being used right now, so I must keep the OutputRoot.MRM design. I'm just trying to optimize the computing code since it has more than 30 lines that are using the full path.

Comment: you need to create a child property before assign: CCREATE FIELD OutputRoot.MRM.PARENT_NODE  TYPE NameValue VALUE 'This is my TestCase';

Comment: If you want to see what is happening in your code then run a trace using the following commands mqsichangetrace mqsireadlog mqsiformatlog. BTW you start using -l debug and stop it with -l none, also use the -r flag to reset so you don't get lots of old stuff that may be there.

Comment: @Bruno It worked! It seems like the references don't really work as with regular SET command with the full path.

Comment: @jmhg92 nice! rank my comment to other with same question.

Comment: @Bruno Sorry, but it seems that I either don't have enough reputation to upvote a comment or I simply don't know how to rank it (I have looked everywhere but I can't find a way to do so). If you could put it as an answer I can mark it as the correct answer though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create a child property before assign:

CREATE FIELD OutputRoot.MRM.PARENT_NODE TYPE NameValue VALUE 'This is my TestCase';